# Example of using Modifier.selectableGroup() in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have two composables:

```
@Composable
fun SelectableGroup() {
    Column(Modifier.selectableGroup()) {
        val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        RadioButton(
            selected = (selectedOption == 0),
            onClick = { onOptionSelected(0) }
        )
        Text("Option 1")
        RadioButton(
            selected = (selectedOption == 1),
            onClick = { onOptionSelected(1) }
        )
        Text("Option 2")
    }
}

@Composable
fun NotSelectable() {
    Column {
        val (selectedOption, onOptionSelected) = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        RadioButton(
            selected = (selectedOption == 0),
            onClick = { onOptionSelected(0) }
        )
        Text("Option 1")
        RadioButton(
            selected = (selectedOption == 1),
            onClick = { onOptionSelected(1) }
        )
        Text("Option 2")
    }
}
```

I have been trying to understand when to use Modifier.selectableGroup() and how lack of it may affect mine composables.
Following this article I removed this modifier but behaviour stayed the same. 
https://fvilarino.medium.com/handling-user-selectable-themes-in-jetpack-compose-c7509784da16

There is another article showing basic composable with 3 radio buttons.

```
@Composable
fun MyUI() {
    val radioOptions = listOf("Mangoes", "Apple", "Melons")

    var selectedItem by remember {
        mutableStateOf(radioOptions[0])
    }

    Column(modifier = Modifier.selectableGroup().background(Color.White)) {

        radioOptions.forEach { label ->
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(56.dp)
                    .selectable(
                        selected = (selectedItem == label),
                        onClick = { selectedItem = label },
                        role = Role.RadioButton
                    )
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
            ) {
                RadioButton(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 16.dp),
                    selected = (selectedItem == label),
                    onClick = null // null recommended for accessibility with screen readers
                )
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And still I can't figure out why this modifier is needed. From the docs:

**Use this modifier to group a list of selectable items like Tabs or RadioButtons together for accessibility purpose**

It doesn't say a lot to me. As removing it from MyUI doesn't cause a change.
Here's article: 
https://semicolonspace.com/radio-button-jetpack-compose/

Comment: The UI doesn't change. It is very important for the accessibility. You should use talkback to fully understand the difference

Comment: Ok. It says not selected on of three items in that case. Is there any other reason for using it?